# SQL Server table automatically manipulated with junk html css code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I recently faced problem with my website [www.zomedia.in](http://www.zomedia.in). I am using *sql server 2005* and *asp.net 4.0* with c#.

My database tables are automatically filled with some unknown html css junk codes such as "Eg: `</title><style>. apyk{position:absolute;clip: rect(438px,auto,auto,438px);} </style><div> c"` (Please Visit http://zomedia.in/ZomediaSongs/ZomediaMp3.aspx and you can see the gridview with junk data in it).

This junk data automatically filled my tables without any human intervention. My website was working fine and I did not change any coding that might have cause the issue. So, I cusulted my hosting provider and they could not give answer. Could this be error with coding or server error?

Comment: SQL injection... Now unless you provide any detail on your code that is all can be said. Mandatory link: [Exploits of a Mom/Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Given that every entry in your page has the same markup, I'd say something is happening when users upload their songs - it looks like markup is getting stored in your database along with the information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually, this happened without any human intervention. It just got updated somewhere (i dont know). Not while upload songs.. it was working fine, then the next day this would happen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hole in your sql queries that allows sql injection. See this article and try to find all instances in your application where data sql statements are being concatenated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I always used parametrized sql query. So, i think there is very less chance of sql injection.. thanks tho

Comment: string sqlstr = "Select * from SongTable where SongArtist like '" + SearchId.Text + "%'";

How can i prevent this from sql Injection?